# Two questions about beginning calculus.

Tags: calculus

Consider points $A=(−9,−9)$ and

$C=(5,−6).$ The point $B$ is on the line passing through

$A$ and $C.$ The $x$-coordinate of $B$ is $0.$

Determine the $y$-coordinate of the point $B.$

and

Choose the value of $k$ that makes the following function continuous at $x=8$:

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} \frac{(x^{2}-11x+24)}{(x-8)} & \text{ when }   x < 8 \\
      -8x+k       &  \text{ when }         x \geq 8.\end{cases}$$

I got 69 for the second one which is wrong. I did this by canceling out $x-8$ so that I got $x-3.$  Is that wrong because $f(x) = x-3$ is different than $\displaystyle{\frac{(x^{2}-11x+24)}{(x-8)}}$ when $x = 8$ so therefore this problem is actually undefined?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your mathematics in a more readable fashion.

Comment: $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-11x+24}{x-8}&\text{for}~x<8\\-8x+kx&\text{for}~x\geq 8\end{cases}$ is perfectly well defined for when $x=8$.  It would be $-64+8k$ for whatever value $k$ is which you should choose to make it continuous.

Comment: $k=69$ is correct for the second question.

Comment: did you get the first one right?

Comment: In the future, it's best to post two unrelated questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

So you are right, in showing that $\displaystyle \frac{x^2-11x-24}{x-8}=x-3$ when $x \neq 8$ (indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$)

Therefore, when $x=8$, $x-3=5$.

We need then, that $-8x+k=5$.

$-8(8)+k=5$, which means that $\boxed{k=69}$.

You good.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first question, use the equation for a line:

\begin{gather*}
y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)
\end{gather*}

For the second question,

In order for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x = 8$, 
\begin{gather}
\lim_{x \to 8^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 8^+} f(x) = f(8)
\end{gather}
In other words, it must evaluate to the same value directly on both sides of $8$ and at $8$ in order to be continuous. You have correctly identified the value of $k$ which makes this statement true to be $69$.

Answer (score 0):

**the first**

We have

$$\vec {AB}//\vec {AC} $$
$$\implies \vec {AB}=k\vec {AC} $$

$\implies 0-(-9)=k (5-(-9)) $ and
$y-(-9 )=k (-6-(-9)) $

$$\implies k=\frac {9}{14}$$
$$\implies y=3k-9=\frac {-99}{14}$$

For the second, observe that

$$x^2-11x+24=(x-8)(x-3) $$

Answer (score 0):

The line can be represented as a 1 dimensional set of points in your space. You can define it by just a direction and an arbitrary point of it. Suppose you know in what direction you have to go if you are given a point of the line like $A$ or $C$. Since the line is straight you can take your chosen point and translate it along that direction. You will land on the line again. You can reach any point just by choosing the right multiple. Let's put this into a formula:
$$
L=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R^2}| \vec{x}=\vec{A}+s(\vec{C}-\vec{A}),s\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
Here the direction is $\vec{C}-\vec{A}$ or $\vec{A}-\vec{C}$, what ever you prefer. The chosen point is $\vec{A}$ and the multiple is a real number $s$. We know the $x$ component of $\vec{B}$ is 0, so we can solve for the $y$ component.$$
\vec{B}=\begin{pmatrix}0   \\  y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-9   \\  -9\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}14   \\  3\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
This gives $0=-9+14s$ and  $y=-9+3s$. That means $s=\frac{9}{14}$ and $y=-9+\frac{27}{14}=-\frac{99}{14}.$